# how to invert a local variable into a global, dot or bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, variables

I was trying to complete my new JavaScript library, and I am trying to finish my function `makeGlobal(variable)`, and I can't seem to figure it out.
My code:

```
_$.makeGlobal = function(variable) {
    window.variable = variable;
};
```

My question:
Does `window.variable = variable` declare the variable as a global, or define a global called `variable` with the value of the local variable, `variable`?
and if it is local, how do I create a global with the paramater of the local `variable`?

Comment: There will be a global variable called `variable` and the value will be the actual value of the parameter `variable`

Comment: @thefourtheye how do I make a global with the name of the local `variable`?

Comment: You seem confused about JS's object property syntax (where `obj["prop"]` is equivalent to `obj.prop`). But regarding globals, why would you need a function to create globals with a name specified in an argument? **What problem are you trying to solve by using globals like this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) it will create global variable with the name literally "variable":

```
window.variable = variable;
```

However with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) it will create global variable with the name stored in `variable`:

```
window[variable] = variable;
```

Comment: ...and this principle applies to properties of all objects, not just the `window` object.